# ssdt :Keeping data with table creation script

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I am creating a database project for an existing database and wants to keep table creation script and its insert script together. I tried following

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1] (
   [ID]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [Desc] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
)

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[t1] ON 
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[t1] ([ID], [Desc]) VALUES 
(1, N'dining'),
(2, N'lounge'),
(3, N'hall'),
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[t1] OFF
GO
```

and it gave error on Insert statement 
'SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context.'

I can recall that I have seen the same in one of my previous project but can't recall how it was done.
Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: As @Ed suggested, using the MERGE statement (idempotent operation) in a post-deployment script is the best practice. He didn't mention its fantastic tool to help you in writing a MERGE statement :) You can find it here: https://the.agilesql.club/Blog/Ed-Elliott/Introducing-MergeUi-Create-And-Edit-Merge-Statements

Answer (score 3):

The normal thing is to have a post deploy script and to put the insert into that, if you make it re-runnable to add "if not exists row .. insert" or my preferred merge statements then even if it is run for every deployment it doesn't matter.

tgriffin is right you can't put DML in a script with the Build action and you can't put DDL statements in a file without build and also have it included in the project.

Comment: Thanks Ed for the suggestion. I actually wanted to put in the table definition file but it doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will happen when you have DML in a script which has a Build Action of "Build". Changing the Build Action to None by right-clicking on the script > Properties > Build Action, should resolve the error.

Comment: Thanks for quick response tgriffin, but changing that property will leave referring objects in error.